# Is there a way to specify argument as collection of a certain model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a function that only accepts an Eloquent `Collection`. This is okay, but really I'd like to specify that it can only accept collections of a certain model. Is it possible to specify that we only want a collection of a certain type to function arguments?

This is what I have now:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as EloquentCollection;

/**
 * @param EloquentCollection $companies
 * @return array
 */
public function transformCompanies(EloquentCollection $companies)
{
    $companies->each(function($company){
       // do things with the company object..
    });
    
}
```

The problem I see with it is that it accepts any type of collection. Could I do something like `public function transformCompanies(CompaniesCollection $companies)` or how does that work? What would the `use` statement be at the top if we wanted this function to only accept an Eloquent collection of the company model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [implement your own class](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) that extends `Collection` and then specify that you'd like to use that for collections of your model. I've never used the functionality, but something like this should work:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Support;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class CompaniesCollection extends Collection {}
```

And then define the `newCollection()` method in your model:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Support\CompaniesCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = []): CompaniesCollection
    {
        return new CompaniesCollection($models);
    }
}
```

And now your controller method can have a signature like this:

```php
public function transformCompanies(App\Support\CompaniesCollection $companies);
```