# Passing Laravel collection by value

Tags: laravel, collections, call-by-value

I'm trying passing an Laravel Eloquent collection into a function, inside the function I'm doing some collection manipulation.
If I do something like `map` method on the collection, it will also alter the underlying models for the outer collection variable.

How can I passing collection by value into a function? I tried `clone` and `->collect()` method, but seems not work.

Thanks.

```
$users = User::where('type', 1)->get();

$this->doSomething($users);
// or
$this->doSomething(clone $users);
// or
$this->doSomething($users->collect());

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $user->location; // has been modified in 'doSomething' function.

}

private function doSomething(Collection $users)
{
    $mapUsers = $users->map(function ($user) {
            $user->location = 'some value';
            return $user;
        });

    // using $mapUsers...
}
```

Comment: Cloning won't work because that just clones the outer `Collection` object, but the individual `User` object references inside it remain the same. Do you need the actual `User` objects in the method? You could just pass `$users->toArray()` instead. Or just clone `$user` in the map callback.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you would have to clone the actual objects contained in the Collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was going to leave this as a comment but it was getting too verbose. When you clone the collection, the references inside remain the same.

You have two options: if you need to work with actual `User` objects, do this:

```php
$users = User::where('type', 1)->get();

$this->doSomething($users);

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->location;
}

private function doSomething(Collection $users)
{
    $mapUsers = $users->map(function (User $user) {
        $u = clone $user;
        $u->location = 'some value';
        return $u;
    });

    // using $mapUsers...
}
```

Or less complicated, if you just need the values, would be to pass an array. The `toArray()` method is recursive, so it turns the inside objects into arrays as well:

```php
$users = User::where('type', 1)->get();

$this->doSomething($users->toArray());

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->location;
}

private function doSomething(array $users)
{
    $mapUsers = collect($users)->map(function (array $user) {
        $user['location'] = 'some value';
        return $user;
    });

    // using $mapUsers...
}
```

Comment: This is correct approach but if you want to declare argument type as collection of specific model, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922052/8129445

Comment: @miken32 Thanks. So the collection object have an $items member which reference the actual models array. Even I use `collect()` method to copy the collection, it will only clone the $items member but not the referenced models. Learned a lesson!